# Assign highlighted state image to Android Image Button

Tags: android, button

I followed steps on other places, and I made an xml file like so:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/yeah2"
        android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/yeah" />
```

My activity xml for my button looks like this:

```
<ImageButton

    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:onClick="play1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:src="@drawable/yeah"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
    android:background="@drawable/highlight" />
```

How to assign highlighted state image to an Android Image Button ?

Comment: my xml file name is highlight.xml

Comment: what is that yeah????

Comment: that's the name of the image button file

Answer (score 0):

make xml like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- Remember: order is important. First matching state(s) is rendered) -->
<item 
    android:state_selected="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/yeah" />
<item 
    android:drawable="@drawable/yeah2" />
```

Then in Java do following

```
imageButton.setImageDrawable(getBaseContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ImageButton));

//set the click listener
imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View button) {
    //Set the button's appearance
    button.setSelected(!button.isSelected());

    if (button.isSelected()) {
        //Handle selected state change
    } else {
        //Handle de-select state change
    }

}

});
```

Comment: I'm new to Android; can you describe what I would put in "Handle selected state change" and "Handle de-selected state change"?

Comment: Its like what you want to do when button is shown highlighted and user clicks it and another case what you want to do when button is not-highlighted  and user clicks it. These are not connected to showing the image. Its just what will happen when user clicks your button :) @DhruvUpadhyay

Comment: ok, so if I don't want anything else to happen except for the image to change, I should leave it blank?

Comment: Yes you can @DhruvUpadhyay